# Computing expectation of product of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be a random variable over $\mathbb{R}$ with density $P_X$. Assume a finite disjoint partition of $\mathbb{R}$, $Z_1,Z_2,\dots, Z_M$. That is, 
\begin{equation}
\bigcup_i Z_i= \mathbb{R}\:\:\:\text{and} \:\:\: Z_i \cap Z_j =\phi
\end{equation}

Let
\begin{equation}
Y=f(X)
\end{equation}
for some real values function $f$.
Let $Q:\mathbb{R}\to \{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_M\}$ be a function with finite range space  where,
 \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
Q&:\mathbb{R}\to \{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_M\}\\
 &:y \to v_i \:\:\:\text{if}, y \in Z_i
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

and define,
\begin{equation}
Z= Q(Y)
\end{equation}
Also define, 
\begin{equation}
P_{kl}=P(Z=v_l|Q(X)=v_k)
\end{equation}
Then show that, 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(XZ)=\displaystyle\sum\limits_{l=1}^Mv_l\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^MP_{kl}\displaystyle\int_{Z_k}xp(x)\,dx
\end{equation}
My try:

I am stuck as I don't know how to proceed. Since $X$ is continuous and $Z$ is discrete I know that the density won't exists, hence I am unable to proceed computing it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you wrote down $P_{kl}$ correctly? I can't make sense of the definition as it stands, since $Q(Y) = Z$. Also, what is the role of $Z_1, ..., Z_k$, besides appearing out of nowhere in the final formula? Does $Q$ map $Z_i$ to $v_i$?

Comment: To elaborate a bit, the current definition of $P_{kl}$ is syntactically correct but it doesn't really make sense, e.g. if the $v_i$ are not natural numbers then all of them are zero.

Comment: I am sorry, I missed out the definition of $Q$. You are right, $Q$ maps $Z_i$ to $v_i$. I have edited the post.

Comment: Also I apologize for the definition of $P_{kl}$, there was a typo. Thank you very much  for pointing it out.

Comment: You need to condition on $Q(x)$ and $Z$, i.e. write $E(XZ)$ as a sum over $k, l = 1, \ldots, M$ of $E(XZ \mid Q(X) = v_k, Z = v_l) P(X \in Z_k, Z = v_l)$. Note here that I've used the fact that $Q(X) = v_k$ if and only if $X \in Z_k$. The second factor in this summand is the product of $P_{kl}$ and $P(X \in Z_k)$. Writing this all out, it remains to show that $E(X \mid Q(X) = v_k) P(X \in Z_k) = \int_{Z_k} x p(x) \; dx$, which follows from the definition of conditional expectation.